# viewBox attribute stops foreignObject textarea from scrolling (using d3 library)

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, textarea

What I want is to make a textarea as a foriegnobject inside an svg and I want that svg to scale automatically to fit the browser width. I can make the textarea but sadly the scrollbar does not work. If I remove the viewBox attribute on the svg, then the scrollbar works but the scaling does not. Here is my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Text Area Test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
</head>
<body>  
<div class="test">
<svg
xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
viewBox="0 0 1113.6298 591.67939"
version="1.1">
</svg>
</div>
</body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="test.js"></script>
</html>
```

And here are the contents of the test.js file

```
var svg = d3.select("svg");

svg.append("foreignObject")
    .attr("width",205)
    .attr("height",380)
    .attr("x",10)
    .attr("y",10)
    .append("xhtml:body")

    .append("textarea")
    .attr("cols",35)
    .attr("rows",31)
    .attr("readonly","true")
    .attr("style","overflow:auto;font-size: 10px")
    .attr("id","My_TextArea");
var textarea;
for(var i=0;i<250;i++)
{
    textarea=document.getElementById("My_TextArea");
    textarea.value = textarea.value+ "\n"+i.toString();
    textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
}
```

I can make the scrollbar on the text area work by removing the viewBox line, but that defeats my ability to have the page scale. How can I make the scrollbar on the textarea work?

Comment: Note that I am using chrome as a browser and that is all I care about for the moment.

Comment: Were you able to find a fix ?